# Create a constant variable link to year and quarter

Tags: r

Hi i am a stata user and i am trying to pass my codes to R. I have a panel data as shown below, and i am looking for a command that can create a constant variable according to which year and quarter the row is located. In stata such command would be reproduced by `gen new_variable = yq(year, quarter)`

My dataframe look like this

```
id     year    quarter   
 1    2007          1     
 1    2007          2     
 1    2007          3     
 1    2007          4     
 1    2008          1     
 1    2008          2     
 1    2008          3     
 1    2008          4     
 1    2009          1     
 1    2009          2     
 1    2009          3     
 1    2009          4     
 2    2007          1     
 2    2007          2     
 2    2007          3     
 2    2007          4     
 2    2008          1     
 2    2008          2     
 2    2008          3     
 2    2008          4     
 3    2009          2     
 3    2009          3     
 3    2010          2     
 3    2010          3
```

I my expected output should look like this: (Values inside new_variable are arbitrary, just looking for a constant value the would be always the same for each year and quarter)

```
id     year    quarter   new_variable
 1    2007          1     220             
 1    2007          2     221          
 1    2007          3     222      
 1    2007          4     223            
 1    2008          1     224      
 1    2008          2     225      
 1    2008          3     226       
 1    2008          4     227      
 1    2009          1     228       
 1    2009          2     229       
 1    2009          3     230      
 1    2009          4     231      
 2    2007          1     220             
 2    2007          2     221           
 2    2007          3     222       
 2    2007          4     223             
 2    2008          1     224       
 2    2008          2     225       
 2    2008          3     226       
 2    2008          4     227       
 3    2009          2     229       
 3    2009          3     230
 3    2010          2     233
 3    2010          3     234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) yearqtr** The `yearqtr` class in the zoo package does this.   `yearqtr` objects have a type of double with the value year + 0 for Q1, year + 1/4 for Q2, etc. When displayed they are shown in a meaningful way; however, they can still be manipulated as if they were plain numbers, e.g. if `yq` is `yearqtr` variable then yq + 1 is the same quarter in the next year.

```
library(zoo)

transform(df, new_variable = as.yearqtr(year + (quarter - 1)/4))
```

**1a)** or

```
transform(df, new_variable = as.yearqtr(paste(year, quarter, sep = "-")))
```

Either of these give:

```
   id year quarter new_variable
1   1 2007       1      2007 Q1
2   1 2007       2      2007 Q2
3   1 2007       3      2007 Q3
4   1 2007       4      2007 Q4
5   1 2008       1      2008 Q1
... etc ...
```

**2) 220** If you specifically wanted to assign 220 to the first date and have each subsequent quarter increment by 1 then:

```
transform(df, new_variable = as.numeric(factor(4 * year + quarter)) + 220 - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Any of these will work:

```
# basic: just concatenate year and quarter
df$new_variable = paste(df$year, df$quarter)

# made for this, has additional options around
# ordering of the categories and including unobserved combos
df$new_variable = interaction(df$year, df$quarter)

# for an integer value, 1 to the number of combos
df$new_variable = as.integer(factor(paste(df$year, df$quarter)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options:

```
library(dplyr) # with dplyr
df %>% mutate(new_variable = group_indices(., year, quarter))

library(data.table) # with data.table
setDT(df)[, new_variable := .GRP, .(year, quarter)]
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = c(2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L), quarter = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "year", "quarter"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```